# Non-uniqueness of Chromatic Polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Consider the path graph of $3$ vertices. Let the vertices be labelled $1,2,3$. Let us start with $x$ colors. I can color the first vertex (vertex $1$) in $x$ ways, the next vertex (vertex $2$) in $x-1$ ways. This gives me the chromatic polynomial as $x(x-1)^2$.

But, now consider coloring the first vertex (vertex $1$) which can be done in $x$ ways. Then, I color the third vertex (vertex $3$), which can be done in $x$ ways (as $1$ and $3$ vertices are not adjacent). The last vertex (vertex $2$) can be colored in $(x-1)$ ways. This gives me the chromatic polynomial as $x^2(x-1)$. What is the reason for the non-uniqueness? Is my calculation wrong in the second case? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second counting is inaccurate.  The number of choices for vertex 2 could be $x-1$ or $x-2$, depending on whether the colors for vertices 1 and 3 are equal.  This variation means you cannot simply multiply $x^2$ by (number of ways to color vertex 2).

Instead this calls for splitting into two cases depending on the color choice for vertex 3:

If vertex 3 has a different color than vertex 1, there are $x-1$ choices for vertex 3 and $x-2$ choices for vertex 2: $x(x-1)(x-2)$ colorings.

If vertex 3 has the same color as vertex 1, there is only one choice for vertex 3 and $x-1$ for vertex 2: $x(1)(x-1)$ colorings.

The two cases sum to exactly $x(x-1)^2$ which matches the simpler argument.

Comment: thanks! so can we use this to determine the chromatic polynomial of a graph which consists of two disjoint subgraphs but meeting at two distinct points?

Comment: on the other hand, this suggests an ordering we should follow while evaluating chromatic polynomial. What is the order specifically?

Comment: It’s not so much that there’s a canonical ordering, but yeah I think the principle here is that you will incur fewer cases if you prioritize vertices that cut off (eliminate dependencies on) previous decisions.  You could start off at vertex 2 and immediately get two disjoint point graphs as subcases.

Comment: Similarly, in the case of two distinct points $u,v$ that separate two otherwise-disjoint graphs, considering the two cases where $u,v$ have the same or different colors allows you to reduce the chromatic polynomial to computing two polynomials for each of the two subgraphs: one where $u,v$ are forced to be equal (equivalent to fusing $u,v$) and one where $u,v$ are forced to be different (equivalent to adding the edge $uv$).

Comment: thanks! so this is just the birkhoff-lewis or whitney's deletion-contraction principle. I think we could use this to prove the Erdos-Faber Lovasz conjecture

Comment: I am not familiar with Birkhoff-Lewis but yes this is exactly the same logic as deletion-contraction.  The only distinction is that we can also treat the disjoint components separately and multiply the results together.  I would be pleasantly shocked if anything Erdös offered a $500 bounty on fell to such a well-understood technique!